# Javascript: Show content according to URL

Tags: javascript, show

My code is supposed to display a text based on a url, the logic is really simple:

if page is the `ht-tp://sitedotcom/thefirstpage (SEF)`, it displays the text, else, if page is `ht-tp://sitedotcom/thesecondpage` the text is hidden. I could put it to work by specifying the absolute url including the file extension, like `ht-tp://sitedotcom/thefirstpage.html,` but I need it to work with the SEF url.

**Here is the code:**

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
var pages = window.location.href;    
if( pages.indexOf( 'http://akecheta.com/free-blogger-templates/' ) > -1 ) {
    document.write('<b>Hello World</b>');
}
else  {
    document.write('');
}
// ]]></script>
```

Replace the url after indexOf with the url on the page you're testing. Remember that this is not supposed to be tested with file extensions.

**THE SOLUTION**
[How can I insert HTML text in Javascript the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685846/how-can-i-insert-html-text-in-javascript-the-right-way)

Comment: You can do it with regexps, or this way `var tocheck = "/free-blogger-templates/"; if (pages.substr(-tocheck.length) == tocheck)` but negative index in substr, as I remember, does not work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Start over with your JavaScript journey, friend.

Comment: I'm afraid my problem is not about document.write

Comment: how does ``(pages.substr(-tocheck.length) == tocheck)`` work? Because I've just made the changes, and it's not working....

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you are trying to perform something based on the URL and i guess you are doing it the right way i.e. to check the URL and perform.

Other way i can suggest is to use query string, based on the query string you can perform certain actions. hope this helps.